# Setting Up ReactJS on .NET Core 2.0, InvalidOperationException

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm in the process of creating a basic .NET Core 2.0 App

`[New]-[Project]-[.NET Core]->[ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)]-[Web Application (No Auth)]`

and trying to add ReactJS by following the tutorial here: (https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html)

When going through the tutorial, however, I get an "InvalidOperationException" error that says: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'React.AspNet.HttpContextLifetimeProvider+PerRequestRegistrations' from root provider.'

Specifically the error comes from the app.UseReact(config=> ... ) section of the tutorial.

Despite my many searches both here and abroad I've come empty-handed, so I reach out to you all here. If this is referenced or already resolved here, please let me know as well.

I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something here.

Assumptions:

- ReactJS 3.1.0 works with Core 2.0 because of 3.0.0 update (https://reactjs.net/2016/10/3.0.0-release.html)
- Visual Studio 2017 Preview (Version 15.3) is viable for ReactJS 3.1.0 (https://reactjs.net/2017/07/3.1.0-release.html mentions 2017 tooling, which isn't enough but thought it could be perhaps?)

---

---

**Update:**

It turns out the problem was that there was a mismatch between the version of React that I had previously installed, and the Visual Studio Project's stated React version.
*The solution was a simple reinstall of React via the command line to align with the project.*

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Note: I was using .net core 2.0 preview1 instead of preview2, which offers React.js templates (and so bypasses the problem). Will follow up some time later about this particular issue though.

Comment: Any news? I'm having the same issue using VS2017.3 preview 7.1 with core 2.0 final

Comment: Oh I updated a package for aspnetcore 2.0 final and that error went away. The started getting some other error about diagnostic source. So I updated to the latest CLI and that problem went away but now the original one is back D:

Comment: got you a hit @ https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/433

Answer (score 15):

see https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/433

change in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

to

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

and `return services.BuildServiceProvider();`

I also had to update/upgrade my node to c6.11.2 (via MSI), but I dont think thats related to your problem.